# Problema com biblioteca android REACT-NATIVE

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Estou utilizando uma biblioteca para cortar fotos em meu projeto, mas ela apenas funciona para android, quando rodo o app no android ele roda normalmente, mas quando roda no ios, da erro na importação da biblioteca, tem algum jeito de quando rodar esse app no ios ele "esquecer" essa biblioteca?

biblioteca: https://github.com/zainozzaini/react-native-android-image-cropper

Answer (score 0):

Use a biblioteca `Platform`

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

// Importe a biblioteca assim:

const ImageCropperPackage = Platform.select({
  ios: () => null,
  android: () => require('com.ozdevcode.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.ImageCropperPackage'),
})();

// OU

const ImageCropperPackage = Platform.select({
  ios: () => require('br.com.outrabiblioteca.ImageCropperPackage'),
  android: () => require('com.ozdevcode.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.ImageCropperPackage'),
})();
```

Com isso é só você usar o componente apenas quando a constante `ImageCropperPackage` for diferente de `null`